# Get one sum from multiple columns

Tags: r

I imagine there is a simple function for this but I can't seem to find it.  I have five columns within a larger data frame that I want to add to get a single sum.  Here's what I did, but I am wondering if there is a much simpler way to get the same result:

```
count <- subset(NAMEOFDATA, select=c(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5))
colcount <- as.data.frame(colSums(count))
colSums(colcount)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum function should do that:

```
 sum(count)
```

Unlike "+" which is vectorized, `sum` will "collapse" its arguments and it will accept a data.frame argument. If some of the arguments are logical, then TRUE==1 and FALSE==0 for purposes of summation, which makes the construction `sum(is.na(x))` possibly useful.

Comment: ha! I knew there had to be an easy way.  These are the kinds of questions one faces during the early stages of SAS -> R transition. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and if you are coming from SAS or SPSS you should pay particular attention to how missing values are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

Always easier with a reproducible example, but here's an attempt:

```
apply( NAMEOFDATA[,paste0("COL",seq(5))], 1, sum )
```